# How can I resize an image from an existing PDF file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit, hummus.js

I have a PDF file that has an image and some text. I want to read that file and then resize the image, and delete the text.

I tried taking a screenshot of the whole PDF with pdf-poppler and then do some image processing with Jimp, it worked but the program is taking too long to finish executing because the images are quite big.

Answer (score 0):

Adnane, you can try to use [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#embed-png-and-jpeg-images).

Comment: pdfDoc.embedJpg(jpgImageBytes) uses an image from outside the pdf file. What I want is to resize an image that exists inside the pdf file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Node.js but the Poppler library comes with a binary `pdftoimages` which extracts all images from a PDF and there is a [Node.js wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-poppler) for Poppler.